# webrequest c# million records

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need some suggestions for some things that I am doing that's taking a 'long time' to run.

1. I have about 100000 records in the database which has a date column. This needs to be updated.
2. This is done by calling a URL for each record and getting date and updating it.
3. Right now, I have written C# code that selects 1000 records at a time.

Code:

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(inputURL);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Read the content. 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The response is in the form of json and so using Jsonserializer I get the date.
And then I update one record at a time.

Now, this is taking a very long time. How can I improve performance of this??

Comment: Do you have direct access to the server? Could you run an app on the server without the web request in the middle? What about direct access to the database?

Comment: Do you only get one item per url/request?

Comment: May `Compression` help ?

Comment: First, do you need to GET the date to update it? Could you use a stored procedure on the database server that updates the records given parameters? This could reduce the number of round-trips. Anything to reduce the number of round-trips. In the past, I've done a bulk-update (say, thousands of records), and then individual updates to one-offs that require specifics changes (say, mark "everything as exported", in one trip, then go back and mark 10 specifics records as failures in another trip).

Comment: @ Corey - I only have access to database.

Comment: @Dave- Yes I only get one item per request.

Comment: @Sriram- what is compression? I am a junior level engr..

Comment: if sending the data over network takes time then `Compression` will help.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis, Can we make webrequests from the SQL server database?? Without calling that I cannot update my DB.

Comment: How are you accessing the database? Why are you doing it via the web? Is that the only access available?Are you using an intermediate web-service? Are the other methods available to access? Can you do a bulk-update through whatever method you are using?

Comment: This is a publicly available data which we use and hence I have to use this Json request for every record

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute sql using SSMS or another method? You haven't specified the rules for updating the date, but if you had a truly simply case, say adding 10 days to every date, you could execute that with one line of code in milliseconds, i.e.

```
update mytable set mydate = dateadd(day, 10, mydate) ...voila.
```

even if you have more complicated rules for updating, you are likely better of doing this thru sql than thru a webrequest one record at a time...

What are the rules for updating the date?

Comment: I can get one date from one json request. So if i need to update 10000, i need 10000 such requests and updates

Answer (score -1):

You can open many URLs to the server simultaneously.  An easy way would be to call this method using TPL (Task Parallelism Library) in .NET (V4 and higher I think, maybe 3.5)

```
List<string> Urls = GetMyList(); 
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach( Urls, u=>Doit(u) );
```

For example, look at the answer here: [Parallel Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347801/parallel-extensions)

You can limit the number of threads which would be active at the same time.

Comment: I have string sqlSel = @"Select Top 1000 ID from myTbl where SDate is null". SqlCommand cmdSel = new SqlCommand(sqlSel, conn_string);
   SqlDataReader reader1 = cmdSel.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader1.Read()){   ID = reader1[0].ToString();
 string inputURL = "http://www.test.com/" + ID + ".json";
 WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(inputURL);
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
 Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();How to use TPL